# Using Wildcards in SQL Query with mysql-connector-python Python 3.6

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

I have a SQL query that works fine when copy pasted into my Python code. There is a line with a parameter that I want to make a variable in my Python script,

```
AND TimeStamp like '%2017-04-17%'
```

So I set a variable in the Python script:

```
mydate = datetime.date(2017, 4, 17) #Printing mydate gives 2017-04-17
```

and change the line in the query to:

```
AND TimeStamp like %s
```

Firstly, when I run the script with the date copy pasted in the query:`cursor.execute(query)` gives no errors and I can print the results with `cursor.fetchall()`

When I set the date to the variable `mydate` and use `%s` and try to run the script, any of these will give me an error:

```
cursor.execute(query,mydate) #"You have an error in your SQL Syntax..."   
cursor.execute(query, ('%' + 'mydate' + '%',)) #"Not enough parameters for the SQL statement"
cursor.execute(query, ('%' + 'mydate' + '%')) #"You have an error in your SQL Syntax..."
cursor.execute(query, ('%' + mydate + '%')) #"must be str, not datetime.date
```

"

I simply want `'%2017-04-17%'` where the `%s` is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the value in your MySQL table is of type `TIMESTAMP` then you will need to do a

`SELECT whatever FROM table where TimeStamp beween '2017-04-17' and '2017-04-18'`

Having created your initial `datetime.date` value then you need to use a `datetime.timedelta(days=1)` on it.

Comment: This worked. Working with a wildcard on the date kept giving me an error. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could format your query before execute it like this:

```
import datetime
mydate = datetime.date(2017,4,17)
query="select * from table where Column_A = 'A' AND TimeStamp like '%{}%'".format(mydate)
query
```

The `query` will be like:

```
"select * from table where Column_A = 'A' AND TimeStamp like '%2017-04-17%'"
```

After that you can pass it to cursor to query:

```
cursor.execute(query)
```

Comment: I found that my query had a wildcard with a name that began with "s", so it looked like '%steve%'. The code was passing the date to that %s, giving it an error.